# What happens if one or more rotors are stopped during autorotation on a quadrotor?

Tags: auto-rotation, quadcopter

I get the basics of autorotation when it comes to a helicopter in unpowered flight, but it's a bit unclear to me when it comes to quadrotors.

My objective is to cover some directed horizontal distance while in freefall and resume control before crashing. I want to do this to save battery, rather than starting controlled flight from the start. If I get horizontally closer to a target location without using much any battery, this is optimal.

Let's say the quad has stable attitude and is in free fall. Then I brake one motor, causing the prop to stop. A naive freebody diagram says the quad will pitch since there's no longer any lift on that side.

My question is what happens after that. Does it reach some **equilibrium position**? Does the decreased upward lift yield **horizontal acceleration** relative to the ground, or will it just **spin in a circle**? Do the rotation directions of the remaining props (2CW/1CCW or 2CCW/1CW) affect what happens next? What if I cut off 2 motors, either next to each other or across from each other?

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to follow this article and find the original study (if this is true). [Algorithm lets quadcopters keep flying on three or less propellers](http://www.gizmag.com/quadcopter-failure-algorithm/30031/). It's claimed it can fly with only one rotor working. Must be clever and use inertia / gyroscopic torque.

Comment: There are a few videos on youtube of a quad going into autorotation, but I feel like my current motors are too stiff anyway. I'm mainly interested in the theory, though.

Comment: http://hackaday.com/2014/02/06/free-falling-quadcopter-experiments-end-with-splat/ In the video at about 1:00, the quad very clearly descends slower than freefall. This is (lower than) the height I'm interested in starting freefall from. But I see I may be mixing up autogyro and autorotation. As far as shutting off the motor, though, if it starts tumbling but is moving even slightly horizontally in the direction I want, that's fine too.

Comment: Thanks. Yes basically the autorotation is like a descending parachute while the autogyro rotor creates lift by converting the horizontal energy from the aft engine like a glider. Re the loss of an engine, the problem is that you need to transfer the 3-axis steering rotations onto 3 rotors, which is possible, but needs a change in the control software (possibly taking advantage of the freewheeling lost rotor). Finally the article for using only 1 or 2 rotors is [here](http://flyingmachinearena.org/wp-content/publications/2014/mueIEEE14.pdf). I'm cleaning some comments above.

Comment: When I brake the one motor, I don't intend on controlling the other 3. Those are still auto-gyro/rotating/doing whatever. I want as much horizontal distance as possible during free fall before I turn all 4 motors on and begin powered flight. This is my plan to save battery, versus falling straight down or beginning controlled flight from the start. I'll edit the question to include that.

Comment: It seems to me that autorotation is going to be hard to control without being able to adjust blade pitch. That's how a helo converts the vertical motion into translational movement. A quad uses a completely different method of directional control that requires power to work. I think tipping it without power will mostly cause it to fall faster since it will reduce the airflow through the props

Comment: @TomMcW falling faster is fine if I can trade that for directed horizontal movement. Before being anywhere near the ground, I would switch the quad's controller to normal mode (vs freefall mode), throttle up all 4 motors, stabilize, and then land slowly.

Comment: @TomMcW: From the video it looks like the prop spins in the opposite direction during free fall. It looks like what marginal control there is is achieved by selectively adding resistance to the motors (can be done if you have control of the ESC software, would be very-very hard with regular PPM signals)

Comment: @MSGhero: Most of the successful autorotation by quads I've seen are done by quads with variable pitch rotors and fixed-speed, governor controlled motor (usually a single central motor). Most homebrew designs are based around heli tail rotors but I've seen a few designs where the rotors are purpose made for the quads.

Comment: @slebetman the props wouldn't spin in opposite direction unless the quad flipped. That's just an artifact of frame rate.

Comment: @TomMcW: Why wouldn't it spin the opposite direction? If you blow air from behind (as in, it's falling) it surely would. I just tried it with my prop. Try it.

Comment: @TomMcW: Also, if the quad flipped then the prop SHOULD spin in the same direction. Not the opposite direction.

Comment: @slebetman I've got brain damage. It will spin in the opposite direction. Sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After watching the video the problem he was having was in keeping it horizontal. It appears that the software isn't able to control the unpowered motors.

I know absolutely nothing about quads but I'm assuming with a fixed rotor pitch they must use variable voltage to the motor to control everything such as translational movement. I'm also assuming they have an accelerometer to determine pitch. The first question is how accurate the accelerometer is at low g's.

Second, when in free fall if a rheostat that is controlled by the computer could be connected across the sides of the motor then your problem could be solved. The freewheeling motors will create a voltage just like a generator so a rheostat would be able to control the current and thus the mechanical resistance to the motor. The rheostat will have an inverse relationship with the mechanical resistance (more electrical resistance less mechanical resistance). How linear that relationship is you'll have to experiment with. If you have the software switch to controlling that resistance it should be able to direct the freefall in the same way it does everything under power, only it will be more limited In its authority. If you do it right you might even be able to use the power generated to recover a little bit of the energy from the fall to charge the batteries like a hybrid car does.

Like I said, I know absolutely zero about quadecopters so I can't fill in any details, but it seems feasible.

Comment: I don't think it's ever been documented before, so I wasn't expecting a solution. However, this definitely puts me on the right track. Thank you @mins